# mkdocs site doesn't exist after build on codeship

Tags: codeship, mkdocs

I'm trying to use codeship to automate building docs from a repository. 
After the Executing the command `mkdocs build --clean` I get a path to where my site folder is supposed to be.

```
INFO    -  Cleaning site directory 
INFO    -  Building documentation to directory: /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/josephkobti/test/site
```

The thing is that I can't find that folder using the ssh console for debugging.

Comment: Hi Joeseph - I would suggest getting in touch with helpdesk.codeship.com and send your build information. They should be able to help you figure out exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the folder not existing was a misunderstanding of Codeship's SSH Debug Build feature, documented here https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/ssh-access/

The VMs started for the debug feature are not the actual VMs that run the automated builds. They are new VMs running the same initialization steps as the automated builds (i.e. cloning the repository, configuring project specific environment variables, ...) but none of the actual setup or test commands.

Because of this the `mkdocs build --clean` command wasn't run either when Joseph connected via to the debug VM, and as such the generated site wasn't available.